# What might cause my program to freeze when deallocing CCScheduler?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Recently, when my game tries to change to another scene, it all freezes. Xcode only reports this:

```
cocos2d: deallocing <CCScheduler: 0x5a9800>
```

I am rather unsure about why is it happening. I have placed some breakpoints, and it seems to be stuck at

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, child)
    child.parent = nil;
```

Which is code from the `CCNode` dealloc method. Although I still can't tell what's up.

This question: [cocos2D deallocing CCScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913470/cocos2d-deallocing-ccscheduler) seems to be having a similar problem as mine. However, as far as I can tell, I've never done anything touch-related recently as he mentions in his answer.

What might be causing this problem? I realize I can't ask you to tell me what is causing it, but a clue is more than enough.

cocos2d-iphone, 1.0.1, iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... I was using `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]popScene]` when transferring instead of `replaceScene`. If I'm not mistaken, there really is no other `CCScene` on a higher tier.